# Some ways to debug code

Tags: buddypress, debug, wp-debug

I have a BuddyPress installation with many custom code.

I had everything ready for production until I moved my database to shared hosting.

The problem is that in strange ocasions, all the activities in `wp_bp_activity` gets deleted.

I'm not saying that this problem ocured because I moved my database, but I cant reproduce this bug with my original installation (but had the same problem when I compied hosting database to new installation on my local machine)

my details:

1) I don't beliave this `DELETE` is triggered with buddypress native code because everything staies as is in `wp_bp_activity_meta`.

2) I can't reproduce this bug and I can't understand when this happens. Also this does not happen often. maybe once or twice a day (or even once in two days). this is why it drives me  crazy )

3) The most interesting, it deletes EVERYTHING except "like". I'm using bp-like-unlike compontent. It deletes everything: avatar_change, comments, activity, my own components but not bp-like which is just a copy of original (liked).

---

UPDATE: As @S_HA_DUM suggested I turned `SQL` debbuging on and found (in 500mb data) this request (no error from php side)

`DELETE FROM wp_bp_activity WHERE item_id = 0`
the only thing I found that queries to `wp_bp_activitiy` is `delete` function (someone named it this simple :D) in buddypress plugin.

but still can't find where this function is triggered

I want some suggestions how to debug this error.
Any help is welcomed

Comment: If you can't debug this it is going to be hard for use to do so. The only suggestion I have is to log errors to a file and turn on SQL logging to see if you can find more clues.

Comment: I log everything except SQL, which sounds kind of good. thanks I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an error and I will write it here

The problem was in my code: I was deleting activites with `item_id` being activity ID deleted. In other words I have a hook which is triggered after activity gets deleted where I delete "BuddyPress LIKE" activity (X Liked a Post).

But there is a `cron` job triggered by BBPress which deletes auto_draft posts (if any). and since BBPress can have an activity in BuddyPress, it also triggeres "DELETE_ACTIVITY", but in this case $activity_id is zero (I don't know, maybe because it does not exist and I'm hooking to early.

and that's where I get `DELETE FROM wp_bp_activity WHERE item_id = 0`

```
function clean_activity_dollars($activity){
    global $wpdb;
    $activity_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'bp_activity';
    $wpdb->delete($activity_table, array( 'item_id' => $activity['id'] ), array('%d'));
}
add_action("bp_before_activity_delete","clean_activity_dollars",10,1);
```

which I changed to this

```
$wpdb->delete($activity_table, array( 'item_id' => $activity['id'], 'type' => 'activity_liked' ), array('%d', '%s'));
```

so even if item_id is zero, it will check for type.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable for debug in wp-config.php, you know, that is great for developing your theme
define('WP_DEBUG', false);